# multiple Bean used in the same form

Tags: java, primefaces, actionlistener

I'm trying to use a menu to manage some outputPanel (with a Bean) in which I put an other form (I've tried whithout but it doesn't work) with some selectOneMenu and some inputText. And so, I manage these things with another Bean.

**ManageApplication.xhtml**

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:form>
    <p:menubar id="menu" autoSubmenuDisplay="true">
        <p:menuitem value="Acceuil"
            actionListener="#{applicationWizard.showHomePanel}"
            icon="ui-icon-home" update="@form" />
        <p:submenu label="Séléction" icon="ui-icon-gear">
            <p:menuitem value="Séléctionner"
                actionListener="#{applicationWizard.showSelectionPanel}"
                update="@form" />
            <p:menuitem value="Créer"
                actionListener="#{applicationWizard.showCreationPanel}"
                update="@form" />
        </p:submenu>
    </p:menubar>
    <p></p>
    <p:panel>
        <p:outputPanel widgetVar="homePanel"
            rendered="#{applicationWizard.viewHomePanel}" autoUpdate="true">
                l33t
            </p:outputPanel>
        <p:outputPanel widgetVar="creationPanel"
            rendered="#{applicationWizard.viewCreationPanel}" autoUpdate="true">
            <h:form>
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <h:outputText value="Référence :" />
                    <p:inputText value="#{createApplicationBean.reference}"
                        style="width:300px;" />

                    <h:outputText value="Client :" />
                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{createApplicationBean.customer}"
                        converter="customerConverter" style="width:300px;">
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="Selectionner" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{createApplicationBean.customers}"
                            var="customer" itemLabel="#{customer.displayed}"
                            itemValue="#{customer}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>

                    <h:outputText value="Type d'application :" />
                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{createApplicationBean.applicationType}"
                        converter="applicationTypeConverter" style="width:300px;">
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="Selectionner" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{createApplicationBean.applicationTypes}"
                            var="applicationType" itemLabel="#{applicationType.displayed}"
                            itemValue="#{applicationType}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>

                    <h:outputText value="Famille d'application :" />
                    <p:selectOneMenu
                        value="#{createApplicationBean.applicationFamily}"
                        converter="applicationFamilyConverter" style="width:300px;">
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="Selectionner" />
                        <f:selectItems
                            value="#{createApplicationBean.applicationFamilies}"
                            var="applicationFamily"
                            itemLabel="#{applicationFamily.displayed}"
                            itemValue="#{applicationFamily}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>

                    <h:outputText value="Pression :" />
                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{createApplicationBean.pressure}"
                        converter="pressureConverter" style="width:300px;">
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="Selectionner" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{createApplicationBean.pressures}"
                            var="pressure" itemLabel="#{pressure.displayed}"
                            itemValue="#{pressure}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>

                    <h:outputText value="Fluide :" />
                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{createApplicationBean.fluid}"
                        converter="fluidConverter" style="width:300px;">
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="Selectionner" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{createApplicationBean.fluids}"
                            var="fluid" itemLabel="#{fluid.displayed}" itemValue="#{fluid}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>

                    <h:outputText value="Cylindrée :" />
                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{createApplicationBean.cylinder}"
                        converter="cylinderConverter" style="width:300px;">
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="Selectionner" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{createApplicationBean.cylinders}"
                            var="cylinder" itemLabel="#{cylinder.displayed}"
                            itemValue="#{cylinder}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>

                    <h:outputText value="Fonctionnement :" />
                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{createApplicationBean.working}"
                        converter="workingConverter" style="width:300px;">
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="Selectionner" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{createApplicationBean.workings}"
                            var="working" itemLabel="#{working.displayed}"
                            itemValue="#{working}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>

                    <h:outputText value="Condensateur permanent :" />
                    <p:inputText value="#{createApplicationBean.permanentCapacitor}"
                        style="width:300px;" />

                    <h:outputText value="Condensateur de démarrage mini :" />
                    <p:inputText value="#{createApplicationBean.miniCapacitorStart}"
                        style="width:300px;" />

                    <h:outputText value="Condensateur de démarrage maxi :" />
                    <p:inputText id="createApplicationMaxiCapacitorStart"
                        value="#{createApplicationBean.maxiCapacitorStart}"
                        style="width:300px;" />

                    <p:commandButton value="Créer" icon="ui-icon-check"
                        actionListener="#{createApplicationBean.create}" />
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
        </p:outputPanel>
        <p:outputPanel widgetVar="selectionPanel"
            rendered="#{applicationWizard.viewSelectionPanel}" autoUpdate="true">
            w00t w00t
        </p:outputPanel>
    </p:panel>
</h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

**CreateApplicationBean.java**

```
package org.bean;

import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.faces.event.ActionListener;

import org.config.Tracer;
import org.objects.ApplicationFamily;
import org.objects.ApplicationType;
import org.objects.Customer;
import org.objects.Cylinder;
import org.objects.Fluid;
import org.objects.Pressure;
import org.objects.Ventilation;
import org.objects.Working;

@ManagedBean ( name = "createApplicationBean" )
public class CreateApplicationBean implements ActionListener {
private String              reference;
private Customer            customer;
private ApplicationType     applicationType;
private ApplicationFamily   applicationFamily;
private Pressure            pressure;
private Fluid               fluid;
private Cylinder            cylinder;
private Ventilation         ventilation;
private Working             working;
private float               permanentCapacitor;
private float               miniCapacitorStart;
private float               maxiCapacitorStart;

public Working getWorking () {
    return working;
}

public void setWorking ( Working working ) {
    System.out.println("CreateApplicationBean.setWorking");
    this.working = working;
}

public Cylinder getCylinder () {
    return cylinder;
}

public void setCylinder ( Cylinder cylinder ) {
    System.out.println("CreateApplicationBean.setCylinder");
    this.cylinder = cylinder;
}

public List<Cylinder> getCylinders () {
    return Cylinder.getAll();
}

public Fluid getFluid () {
    return fluid;
}

public void setFluid ( Fluid fluid ) {
    System.out.println("CreateApplicationBean.setFluid");
    this.fluid = fluid;
}

public List<Fluid> getFluids () {
    return Fluid.getAll();
}

public Pressure getPressure () {
    return pressure;
}

public void setPressure ( Pressure pressure ) {
    System.out.println("CreateApplicationBean.setPressure");
    this.pressure = pressure;
}

public List<Pressure> getPressures () {
    return Pressure.getAll();
}

public ApplicationFamily getApplicationFamily () {
    return applicationFamily;
}

public void setApplicationFamily ( ApplicationFamily applicationFamily ) {
    System.out.println("CreateApplicationBean.setApplicationFamily");
    this.applicationFamily = applicationFamily;
}

public List<Ventilation> getVentilations () {
    return Ventilation.getAll();
}

public List<ApplicationFamily> getApplicationFamilies () {
    return ApplicationFamily.getAll();
}

public List<ApplicationType> getApplicationTypes () {
    return ApplicationType.getAll();
}

public List<Customer> getCustomers () {
    return Customer.getAll();
}

public List<Working> getWorkings () {
    return Working.getAll();
}

public String getReference () {
    return reference;
}

public void setReference ( String reference ) {
    System.out.println("CreateApplicationBean.setReference");
    this.reference = reference;
}

public Customer getCustomer () {
    return customer;
}

public void setCustomer ( Customer customer ) {
    System.out.println("CreateApplicationBean.setCurstomer");
    this.customer = customer;
}

public ApplicationType getApplicationType () {
    return applicationType;
}

public void setApplicationType ( ApplicationType applicationType ) {
    System.out.println("CreateApplicationBean.setApplicationType");
    this.applicationType = applicationType;
}

public Ventilation getVentilation () {
    return ventilation;
}

public void setVentilation ( Ventilation ventilation ) {
    System.out.println("CreateApplicationBean.setVentilation");
    this.ventilation = ventilation;
}

public float getPermanentCapacitor () {
    return permanentCapacitor;
}

public void setPermanentCapacitor ( float permanentCapacitor ) {
    System.out.println("CreateApplicationBean.setPermanentCapacitor");
    Tracer.println("CreateApplicationBean.create");
    this.permanentCapacitor = permanentCapacitor;
}

public float getMiniCapacitorStart () {
    return miniCapacitorStart;
}

public void setMiniCapacitorStart ( float miniCapacitorStart ) {
    Tracer.println("CreateApplicationBean.create");
    this.miniCapacitorStart = miniCapacitorStart;
}

public float getMaxiCapacitorStart () {
    return maxiCapacitorStart;
}

public void setMaxiCapacitorStart ( float maxiCapacitorStart ) {
    Tracer.println("CreateApplicationBean.create");
    this.maxiCapacitorStart = maxiCapacitorStart;
}

public void create ( ActionEvent actionEvent ) {
    Tracer.println("CreateApplicationBean.create");
    System.out.println("CreateApplicationBean.create");
    FacesMessage msg = null;
    msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL,
            "Erreur lors de la création.", "");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
}

@Override
public void processAction ( ActionEvent event )
        throws AbortProcessingException {
    Tracer.println("CreateApplicationBean.processAction");

}

}
```

**ApplicationWizard.java**

```
package org.wizard;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

import org.objects.Application;


@ManagedBean
public class ApplicationWizard {
private Application selectionnedApplication ;
private boolean viewHomePanel = true;
private boolean viewCreationPanel = false;
private boolean viewSelectionPanel = false;

public Application getSelectionnedApplication() {
    return selectionnedApplication;
}

public void setSelectionnedApplication(Application selectionnedApplication) {
    this.selectionnedApplication = selectionnedApplication;
}

public void showHomePanel ( ActionEvent evt ) {
    showHomePanel ();
}

public void showHomePanel () {
    this.viewHomePanel = true ;
    this.viewCreationPanel = false ;
    this.viewSelectionPanel = false ;
}

public boolean isViewHomePanel() {
    return viewHomePanel;
}

public void setViewHomePanel(boolean viewHomePanel) {
    this.viewHomePanel = viewHomePanel;
}

public void showCreationPanel ( ActionEvent evt ) {
    showCreationPanel ();
}

public void showCreationPanel () {
    this.viewHomePanel = false ;
    this.viewCreationPanel = true ;
    this.viewSelectionPanel = false ;
}

public boolean isViewCreationPanel() {
    return viewCreationPanel;
}

public void setViewCreationPanel(boolean viewCreationPanel) {
    this.viewCreationPanel = viewCreationPanel;
}

public void showSelectionPanel ( ActionEvent evt ) {
    showSelectionPanel ();
}

public void showSelectionPanel () {
    this.viewHomePanel = false ;
    this.viewCreationPanel = false ;
    this.viewSelectionPanel = true ;
}

public boolean isViewSelectionPanel() {
    return viewSelectionPanel;
}

public void setViewSelectionPanel(boolean viewSelectionPanel) {
    this.viewSelectionPanel = viewSelectionPanel;
}

}
```

I've tried to use one Bean without the other, and they work... But when I combinate them... they don't.

Comment: Only looking at the facelet code, I notice an `<h:form>..</h:form>` inside another. This is not valid html and can lead to undesired side effects. I recommend to first clean up your facelet code and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

i think u should put the scoope of Managed Bean

like this :

```
@ManagedBean(name="beanName")
@ViewScooped
```

because, if u dont put the scoope..
those managed bean will get the default scoope, which is

```
@RequestScooped
```

so that `ManagedBean` will be 'alive' for an `HTTP` request..

`CMIIW`

Answer (score 0):

I SOLVE IT !!!

I've had this to the ApplicationWizard class :

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class ApplicationWizard {
```